# Retrieve images from html

Tags: php, image, url

Is there a method or anything that can search through the html source of a page and return the href value of the nth image. The value should be fetched thus script.php?url=google.com"

Comment: can you use client side scripting like javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 2):

```
// Load page as a string
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
// Create new DOM document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Load HTML
@$doc->loadHTML($homepage);
// Array of imagetags
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
// Loop trough array and echo the url
foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Look these up:

- [`DOMDocument::loadHtmlFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)
- [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)
- [`DOMNodelist::item`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php)